# Fill junction table by matching values in linked tables

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert, junction-table

I have a database with several articles and corresponding images (laying in different folders)

There are 3 folders with Images of the products

> In one folder only technical images, in the other marketing images, in
>   the third are high quality images for printing purposes

To retrieve product information or images faster we use 'slugs', the Article Number is stripped from any character besides digits

i did the same on the image table, but hence there are a lot of images linked to one product (and sometimes one image is linked to different products) i would like to link them in a junction table

is it possible to fill the junction table with the IDs based on comparing the value in `tblArticles`.`articleSlug` and `tblArticlepictures`.`articlepictureSlug`

I found this resource, but it is based on a 1 to many relationship

[How do I insert into a table from another table by matching on values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17118658/how-do-i-insert-into-a-table-from-another-table-by-matching-on-values)

---

```
CREATE TABLE `tblArticles` (
  `articleID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articleSlug` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `articleComment` varchar(1500) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`articleID`),
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblArticlepictures` (
  `articlepictureID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articlepictureYear` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `articlepicturePath` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `articlepictureSlug` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`articlepictureID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `articlepicturePath_UNIQUE` (`articlepicturePath`),
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `tblRefArticleArticlepicture` (
  `refArticleArticlepictureID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `articleIDRef` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `articlepictureIDRef` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`refArticleArticlepictureID`),
  KEY `fk_tblRefArticleArticlepicture_tblArticles1_idx` (`articleIDRef`),
  KEY `fk_tblRefArticleArticlepicture_tblArticlepictures1_idx` (`articlepictureIDRef`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblRefArticleArticlepicture_tblArticlepictures1` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`articlepictureIDRef`) REFERENCES `tblArticlepictures` (`articlepictureID`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_tblRefArticleArticlepicture_tblArticles1` 
  FOREIGN KEY (`articleIDRef`) REFERENCES `tblArticles` (`articleID`) 
  ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

---

```
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| Picture           | Folder            | Article           | Slug (in both tables) |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| APS-4216_wr.jpg   | W                 | APS-4216T         | 4216                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| APS-9669 .jpg     | W                 | APS-9669          | 9669                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| APS-2719NC.jpg    | W                 | APS-2719          | 2719                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| EAP-3277T.jpg     | W                 | EAP-3277          | 3277                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| EAP-8717T_1.jpg   | W                 | EAP-8717Z         | 8717                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| EAP-4530T.jpg     | W                 | EAP-4530A         | 4530                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| ----------------- | ----------------- | ----------------- | -----------------     |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| APS-4216 t.jpg    | P                 | APS-4216T         | 4216                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| APS-9669_wr.jpg   | P                 | APS-9669          | 9669                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| APS-2719 .jpg     | P                 | APS-2719          | 2719                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| EAP-3277NC.jpg    | P                 | EAP-3277          | 3277                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| EAP-8717T.jpg     | P                 | EAP-8717Z         | 8717                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
| EAP-4530T_1.jpg   | P                 | EAP-4530A         | 4530                  |
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into tblRefArticleArticlepicture (articleIDRef, articlepictureIDRef)
select articleID as articleIDRef, articlepictureID as articlepictureIDRef
        from tblArticles a
        join tblArticlepictures p
        ON a.articleSlug = p.articlepictureSlug
        where a.articleSlug =p.articlepictureSlug
```